# Error in app.js file in react-native project

Tags: react-native

Im getting an error right where im declaring the app component in my react-native project app.js. It says: "Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type annotation at function return"
How can I solve this?

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Navigation from './src/navigation';

/* $FlowFixMe[missing-local-annot] The type annotation(s) required by Flow's
 * LTI update could not be added via codemod */

const App = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#121211', flex: 1}}>
    <StatusBar barStyle={'light-content'} />
    <Navigation />
  </SafeAreaView>
  );
};




export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import React with the types -

```
import * as React from 'react';
```